# Find keywords in tkinter text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I found this answer in overflow and I don't know what the problem is?
Many others have asked this question but all of the answers are outdated or just give me more errors.

I need some help with highlighting keyword or change the color of them. My brain is blow up with creating tags over and over

```
from tkinter import *

#dictionary to hold words and colors
highlightWords = {'if': 'green',
                  'else': 'red'}

def highlighter(event):
    ''' the highlight function, called when a Key-press event occurs'''
    for k,v in highlightWords.iteritems():
        startIndex = '1.0'
        while True:
            startIndex = text.search(k, startIndex, END)
            if startIndex:
                endIndex = text.index('%s+%dc' % (startIndex, len(k)))
                text.tag_add(k, startIndex, endIndex)
                text.tag_config(k, foreground=v)
                startIndex = endIndex
            else:
                break

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.bind('<Control-Key-p>', highlighter)
```

With this code I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: You have to use `items()` instead of `iteritems()` in Python 3.

Comment: Please don't post code as images, since it can make it hard to copy-paste into an editor, or they may be even inaccessible for people with low bandwidth. Instead, copy-paste your code, select it and press the brackets icon in the question editor.

Comment: You can click the edit button under your post to edit it and change the code to text and format it instead of image

Comment: Hello Hamed and welcome to StackOverflow. please edit your post and remove the whole link under your paragraph, instead of this, add a hyperlink into "this answer" to increase readbality.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following

```
from tkinter import *

#dictionary to hold words and colors
highlightWords = {'if': 'green',
                  'else': 'red'}

def highlighter(event):
    ''' the highlight function, called when a Key-press event occurs'''
    for k,v in highlightWords.items():
        startIndex = '1.0'
        while True:
            startIndex = text.search(k, startIndex, END)
            if startIndex:
                endIndex = text.index('%s+%dc' % (startIndex, len(k)))
                text.tag_add(k, startIndex, endIndex)
                text.tag_config(k, foreground=v)
                startIndex = endIndex
            else:
                break

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.bind('<Control-Key-p>', highlighter)

root.mainloop()
```

You need to use `.items()` rather than the outdated `.iteritems()`

Pressing Ctrl + P will then highlight instances of the words if/else.